# How to deploy new Logic app to existing API management from other resource group using ARM templates

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-group

I'm trying to add a new logic app to existing API management instance using ARM template. Is there any way to refer to an APIM instance from another resource group using ARM template? New logic app and existing APIM are in different resource groups under the same subscription.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use `resourceId()` function to achieve that.

```
"[resourceId('otherResourceGroup', 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', 'apim_name')]"
```

you can use the method above to reference resources in another resource group. more reading:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#resourceid